# Find the ? in this grid

Tags: logical-deduction, formation-of-numbers, grid-deduction

> Find question mark in this grid with numbers.

[image]

csv version:

```
9,6,7,3
2,4,7,6
4,1,5,8
3,0,3,?
```

Hint: You use all numbers to find ? and it is much more simple calculation than you think!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is

> 9

Explanation:

> The grid represents a subtraction operation:
>
> ```
>   9673 
> - 2476
>   4158
>  -----
>   3039
> ```

Comment: or $2476+4158+3039 = 9673$

Answer (score -1):

Answer could be

> 2

As,

> the sum of all the numbers of small squares should equate to sum of numbers formed by the bigger suqares (from Right bottom to Top left)

That is for example:

> ? = ? (square of size 1 X 1)
>  0 + 1 + 4 + 7 + 6 = 3 + 5 + 8 + ? (of size 2 X 2) - thereby giving ?=2 and
>  similarly for size  4 X 4.